# Populating Nested Repeater Drop Downs

Tags: c#, .net, linq, drop-down-menu, repeater

I have nested repeaters that create a table with each cell consisting of 3 dropdowns. I set the selected value of the dropdowns by looping through the repeaters and assigning them to the result of a LINQ statement.

The number and characteristic dropdowns work fine, but the make dropdowns all get set to the last value assigned. Does anyone have any clue why this is happening?

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
        </tr>
    <asp:Repeater id="PriorityRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="PriorityBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="Priority" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Priority") %>' />
                    <%# Eval("Priority") %>
                </td>
                <asp:Repeater ID="DayRepeater" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="Day" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Day") %>' />
                            <!--%# Eval("Day") %-->
                            <label>Vehicles</label>
                            <asp:DropDownList id="dailyNumber_dd" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="5" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="10" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="15" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="25" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="30" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="35" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="40" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="45" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <br /><br />
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="dailyCharacteristic_dd" style="font-size:small">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="New Inventory" Value="newest" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Old Inventory" Value="oldest" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Lowest Price" Value="cheap" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Highest Price" Value="expensive" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Oldest Year" Value="oldyear"/>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Newest Year" Value="newyear" Selected="True"/>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <br /><br />
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="dailyMake_dd" Width="108" style="font-size:small"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </table>


foreach (RepeaterItem row in PriorityRepeater.Items)
            {
                HiddenField myPriority = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("Priority");
                Repeater DayRepeater = (Repeater)row.FindControl("DayRepeater");
                foreach (RepeaterItem col in DayRepeater.Items)
                {
                    DropDownList dailyMake_dd = (DropDownList)col.FindControl("dailyMake_dd");
                    DropDownList dailyNumber_dd = (DropDownList)col.FindControl("dailyNumber_dd");
                    DropDownList dailyCharacteristic_dd = (DropDownList)col.FindControl("dailyCharacteristic_dd");
                    HiddenField myDay = (HiddenField)col.FindControl("Day");
                    string thisDay = myDay.Value.ToString().ToLower();
                    string thisPriority = myPriority.Value.ToString();

                    tAutoSelection thisSelection = (from a in theSelections where a.day == thisDay select a).Single<tAutoSelection>();
                    if (thisPriority == "1")
                    {
                        //dailyMake_dd.SelectedValue = thisSelection.makes1;
                        dailyMake_dd.SelectedIndex = 5;
                        dailyNumber_dd.SelectedValue = thisSelection.num1.ToString();
                        dailyCharacteristic_dd.SelectedValue = thisSelection.char1;
                    }
                    else if (thisPriority == "2")
                    {
                        dailyMake_dd.SelectedIndex = 3;
                       // dailyMake_dd.SelectedValue = thisSelection.makes2;
                        dailyNumber_dd.SelectedValue = thisSelection.num2.ToString();
                        dailyCharacteristic_dd.SelectedValue = thisSelection.char2;
                    }
                    else if (thisPriority == "3")
                    {
                        dailyMake_dd.SelectedIndex = 9;
                       // dailyMake_dd.SelectedValue = thisSelection.makes3;
                        dailyNumber_dd.SelectedValue = thisSelection.num3.ToString();
                        dailyCharacteristic_dd.SelectedValue = thisSelection.char3;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where are you populating the contents of the "make" DDL?

Comment: The "make" DDL gets populated by a SQL stored procedure that returns all unique vehicle makes in the user's inventory.

Comment: When do you populate the "make" DDL?  I don't see its DataSource set so is it done in the code behind?  If so at what time, e.g. Load, PreRender, etc.?